# Catch Windows Explorer file save event

Tags: windows, shell, events, save

I'm developing Windows Shell Extension, trying to check some criteria before a file (any type of file) is being saved. So my question is, is it possible to catch Windows Explorer file Save event? Or are there any ways to accomplish my task?